# How to generate unique payment URL using Paypal?

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to work out how I can generate a unique payment token that I can redirect users to so they can pay for a digital item.

I think the [Button Manager SDK](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/button-manager) is what I need. However, I can not see how I can set the receiver email? For a particular item, there is a different receiver and I want to dynamically set this.

However, it seems I just have to set my credentials as the receiver. I want to use many receivers for different items rather than one sdk config file.

What I currently use is simply a HTML Paypal button but I'd rather dynamically create a unique URL to redirect a user to stop users tampering with things.

Comment: I would really like an answer to this too, hence the bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the Express Checkout API?  -- (perhaps with SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole to allow guest checkout?)

I believe it's a better tool for this job; token redirection is a core feature of EC.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Which method would you recommend in the express checkout API? I ask because it still seems to want me to add API credentials? Can I overwrite the person receiving payment to be anyone?

Comment: Facilitating an EC sale-type payment to someone else's account is called a 'unilateral' payment, and yes you can do this by passing 'SUBJECT' to be their email address.

How many different accounts will you be sending payments to--and what's your general business relationship with them?

Comment: I am basically running a site that allows others to sell digital goods via Paypal, as the site owner, I am not a merchant but the sellers are. The sellers have valid Paypal accounts and they should receive payments from other users. Does this make sense and is it possible with EC?

Comment: If 100% of the payment is going from the buyer to the seller, EC should work well for this.  If not 100%, you may want to consider Adaptive Payments' Chained Payments

Comment: Can you specify what methods in EC and how would setting the receiver of the payment be set?

Comment: You would make use of the Set/Get/Do EC methods as normal, and you would pass SUBJECT=email@domain.com to set the receiver